# Delete consecutive lines if patterns match in each line

Tags: bash, sed, awk, grep

Good day,

I was wondering how to delete to consecutive lines when this pattern is found: `/^pt [a-z]\npy [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\n//`

**Expected Input**

```
pt a
py 01234
pt b
cd abc
py 5678
```

**Expected Output**

```
pt b
cd abc
py 5678
```

Thank so much in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed '/^pt [a-z]/{N;/py [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/d}' your_file
```

**Expanation**

- If the current line matches `/^pt [a-z]/` we execute what's between braces.
- `N` appends the next line to the active buffer.
- If the active buffer now matches `/py [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]/`, we delete (i.e. we don't print) the contents of the active buffer. This is accomplished by `d`.

Comment: Thank so much for helping me out, it works smoothly. Have a nice day : )

Comment: You can substitute `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]` by `[0-9]\{4\}`

Answer (score 0):

Through Perl,

```
$ perl -00pe 's/^pt [a-z]\npy [0-9]{5}\n//' file
pt b
cd abc
py 5678
```