# Reading specific lines from input file

Tags: linux, sed, awk, grep

I have  an input file with this general structure. **I only want to extract the values step and weight from the hill blocks and put them into a output file using awk/sed/grep. Hill blocks are arranged in similar fashion throughout in the input file.**

Edit : 
I am using MAC OSX.

```
 configuration {
 step         5000
 dt 2.000000e+00
 }

colvar {
name d1
x  1.70882305580118e+01
v  0.00000000000000e+00
}

1.85104129628346e-02 9.71380137561312e-02 4.00538287370335e-02
1.25662994200839e-02 9.88655406140091e-02 1.41657757894898e-01

hill {
step            0
weight    1.00000000000000e-01
centers   1.23563844380284e+02
widths    1.25331413731550e+00
}
 hill {
 step          100
 weight    1.00000000000000e-01
centers   1.19065310650377e+02
widths    1.25331413731550e+00
}
```

Through some other answers I manage to found some help :-

```
 sed 's/^.*weight//' diol_colvar.colvars.state > hill.txt
 sed 's/^.*step//' diol_colvar.colvars.state > hill.txt
```

Sadly this is not working as I wanted.

I want my output something like this :-

```
  0     1.00000000000000e-01
  100   1.00000000000000e-01
```

Please help me sort this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: from what I can understand, you want step and weight values only from `hill` blocks and put the values side by side? is that correct?

Comment: @sp asic yes, sorry if I dint make it clear.

Comment: no issues.. but some more details will help in simpler solution... are `step` and `weight` are guaranteed to be next to each other? is there a chance of them appearing next to each other outside `hill` blocks?

Comment: @sp asic yes, all hill blocks are arranged in similar fashion and step and weight are always appearing similarly.

Comment: alright, please add these details to question, while I will try to give an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) With `sed`

Assuming `step` and `weight` occur in consecutive lines,

```
$ sed -nE '/step/{N;s/.*step\s+(\S+).*\n.*weight\s+(\S+).*/\1\t\2/p}' ip.txt 
0   1.00000000000000e-01
100 1.00000000000000e-01
```

- `-nE` do not print lines by default and use extended regex
- `/step/` match if lines containing `step`
- `N` to get the next line

**Note:**

The above was tested on `GNU sed 4.2.2`. The below might help on OS X and other versions. See [this Q&A on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178924/os-x-sed-e-doesnt-accept-extended-regular-expressions) for details, main point being `\s` might not work same as GNU sed

```
sed -nE '/step/{N;s/.*step[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+).*\n.*weight[[:space:]]+([^[:space:]]+).*/\1\t\2/p}' ip.txt
```

---

2) With `awk`

```
$ awk 'a ~ /step/ && /weight/{print v"\t"$2} {a=$0; v=$2}' ip.txt 
0   1.00000000000000e-01
100 1.00000000000000e-01
```

- `{a=$0; v=$2}` saves the line and second field
- `a ~ /step/ && /weight/` match if previous line contains `step` and current line contains `weight`

Assuming the `hill` blocks are all similar to input given, we can match three consecutive lines to restrict the match only to `hill` blocks

```
awk 'b ~ /hill/ && a ~ /step/ && /weight/{print v"\t"$2} {b=a; a=$0; v=$2}' ip.txt
```

To save the results, add `> output_filename` to end of command

Reference:

- [sed pattern matching on consecutivelines](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165362/delete-consecutive-lines-if-patterns-match-in-each-line)

Comment: awk works fine for me. Thanks a lot man, I wish I could have liked it (less reputation). However,  sed solution shows this error (sed: 1: "/step/{N;s/.*step\s+(\S ...": bad flag in substitute command: '}' )

Comment: @VikasDubey, glad to hear it works.. see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) for next steps :)

Comment: @VikasDubey, what is your `sed` version? it works for me on `GNU sed 4.2.2`

Comment: does sed work on OS x ?

Comment: @VikasDubey, see http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13711/differences-between-sed-on-mac-osx-and-other-standard-sed and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30003570/how-to-use-gnu-sed-on-mac-os-x

Comment: @vikasDubey, see the answer and ensuing comment by same author to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178924/os-x-sed-e-doesnt-accept-extended-regular-expressions. sp asic's `sed` one-liner is correct, but does not apply to "OS X", because `-E` means _extended regex_, but not _enhanced extended_ as OS X would **need** it to be. In OS X _extended regex_ does not include the syntax `\s`  to account for _space_ as it normally does for GNU `sed` on a non-Apple GNU linux OS. So it's normal to see that `sed` one-liner fails for you. See what you get if you replace `\s` by `[:space:]` ...

Comment: sp asic: Can you modify your answer to reflect the above ? --- @vikasDubey: Can you include OS X somewhere in OP or in yr title, so people are not thrown off by subtle differences such as described above ?  After modification of sp asic's answer, you could perhaps do everyone a favor by **accepting** it as the good answer. For that use the green check mark left of his/her answer. ;-)

Comment: @Cbhihe, thanks for the pointer on OS X issue, updated the answer

Comment: @VikasDubey: In my comment above, you might want to try `[[:space:]]` rather than `[:space:]`. I am not clear on which of the two you should use for lack of an appropriate OS X box on which to check. I think `[[:space:]]` should work better. Buuuut...  check `man sed`on your box in any case. Sorry for not being completely water-tight on that one...

Answer (score 0):

More easy to use awk twice: first time to extract `hill { }` block and second to extract step/weight values.

```
awk '/hill *{/,/}/ {print}' \
   | awk '$1 == "step" { st = $2 }; $1 == "weight" { print st "\t" $2}'
```

This command will work only if `weight` comes after `step` but not necessary on consecutive lines.